# #next_sync_token fo Google Calendar Events always return nil

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client

I created 3 events in Calendar, then I run

```
response = @client.execute!(
   :api_method => @calendar_api.events.list,
   :parameters => {
     :calendarId => "primary",
     :maxResults => 10,
     :singleEvents => true,
     :orderBy => 'startTime'}
 )
```

I received 3 items but `#next_sync_token` method called on `response.data` returns nil (#`next_page_token` also returns nil but in this case it is correct). I tried to set :fields parameter to "nextSyncToken" but still nothing. I also made some updates on that events and `#next_sync_token` was still set to nil..Am I wrong? Maybe I made some mistake ?
The call only with `calendarId` in parameters do the same.

Answer (score 12):

Get rid of orderBy.  This isn't documented, but if you try the Google API, you'll see that nextSyncToken isn't returned with orderBy: startTime.

Wasted lots of time on the same issue.

Comment: This was definitely the problem for me! Thanks for much for posting this. The Google Calendar API docs need work.

Comment: Thank you--would have never found this!

Comment: Wow. Lame, thanks for sharing. Saved me who knows how much time.

Answer (score 0):

The result will only have the next sync token on the last page. You need to go over all the pages (until next_page_token nil) and then you will find a sync token.

Comment: Yes It is true and I know this, but here I have only 3 events so I have only 1 page and it is the last. In this case I think that #next_sync_token should respond with proper token. I also see that response.body contains  nextSyncToken, so that method should work

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to try if you aren't getting the `next_sync_token` is to add it to the fields parameter:

**Example:**

```rb
params = {
  max_results: 100,
  fields: 'items(id,summary,description),next_sync_token',
}

result = calendar_service.list_events 'primary', **params
```